# Importing C++ Functions as Blueprint Nodes

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm working with some friends within Unreal Engine 4, and I'm running the latest version. What I'm wondering is if it is possible to bring a function from C++ into blueprint as a node, as some of us are working in blueprint and some in C++.

Comment: Sounds like a question for the Unreal forums.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have two possibilities to do this:

1. Create a [BlueprintFunctionLibrary](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprint_Function_Library,_Create_Your_Own_to_Share_With_Others) with static C++ functions. You can call them from every blueprint.
2. If you want to import methods from a class then this class has to extend a UObject (like AActor). You can only call these nodes from a blueprint if you have a respective object to call them on. For the C++ part, you have to annotate the desired method with the UFUNCTION macro:
   `UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = YourCategory)`